# How to design a relational DB for a player playing mutiple sports?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am trying to create a DB Design where one user plays more than 1 sport. Eg. user1 plays Hockey, soccer, tennis.

What would be the best design for storing the multiple sports against 1 player?

Comment: Probably 3 tables - Players, Sports and Player_Sports (as a 1-to-many relationship between Players and Sports).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a many to many relation, the way you can make it is creating a player_sport Table, which will have a double primary key, formed by the pk from both Tables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now, there is a also a Team_table which is again a many-to-many relationship with the player table. How do you think I can relate it with Player and Sports table?

Comment: if you make a relation between team and player, it will be related to the sport table through the player_sport Table. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: Yes, it certainly does. That was something I am trying. Just wanted to make sure if there was any better technique. I don't mind having a de-normalized table, but I don't prefer to use too many join which will affect the performance of my query

Comment: if you don't care about having a de-normalized db, you could establish a one to many relation between sport and team